# Best calendar control available in .net to implement drag and drop from treeview onto calendar

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want in my asp.net application is to create a schedule.The events should be dragged from the treeview and dropped onto the calendar control to create the schedule.What i want is that someone could suggest what is the best calendar control available in the market to do so.My budget is 300$.If there is some other way of achieving this then do tell me

Answer (score 1):

I use [Telerik's RadScheduler for ASP.NET AJAX](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/outlook2007/defaultcs.aspx) and I'm very satisfied with it.

But it costs $799, or [10k reputation points in Stack Overflow](https://www.telerik.com/registration-login/stackoverflowregistration.aspx).

Comment: The cost is too much,can i get only the calendar control not the whole pack

Comment: The '10k reputation' link no longer seems to land on the stackoverflow special price page.

Comment: @KraangPrime, I think that link went dead a few years ago

Answer (score 1):

Tarun,

Not exactly what you've described, but perhaps a good starting point. this is a jquery calendar app that just 'works'. i've used it in several 'simple' projects with ease.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

let me know if this is of any use in your scenario.

jim